# Does compiler compile includes as well?

Tags: c++

When I compile a SDL project on C++ it creates an executable for me. When I run that executable it doesn't work if I don't have SDL.dll in the same directory. I understand that because it needs to find all the libraries and APIs that are being used.

But when I create my own library and include it in the code, why doesn't it need to be in the same directory? Why can it be completely deleted and the executable would still run? What is the difference between my own library and SDL in example?

Comment: Do you compile your own library as static lib?

Comment: I meant my own header and cpp files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what the compiler compiles is a translation unit, or a compilation unit. This includes the headers for each cpp file.

Then you have the linker. This links your compiled code into a usable form.

The .dlls is likely searched for and included when your application runs.

When you use your own library you probably include it into your program in the link step. (static linkage) You can delete it because it is no longer needed.

(Because the details you have given is a bit unclear - this may or may not be the whole story )

Answer (score 0):

Im not an expert but i think this info could be useful

Compilation depends on the compilator used but it usually takes 4 steps, this is an example of GCC:

- pre-processing
- compilation
- assembly
- linking

In the first step the compilator replaces the includes generating a .i file, this file has the included headers but not the implementation of those.

In the compilation step, the compiler processes the .i file and outputs a .s file, this file contains the program translated to assembly, no implementations yet.

In the third step, .s file is translated to machine code, generating a .obj binary file (usually in ELF format since a.out is deprecated, the file extensions is just heritance)

In the fourth step, all .obj files are linked with other .obj and static libraries, here, the code of all of them merges in a final executable.

If after linking and running there's a function not implemented but a dynlib has been declared as needed in the linking step, the program will look for it in the host machine, that's what is happening to you with SDL.

There are 2 possible fixes to your problem.

- (correct) ship SDL2.dll with your binary and set it up in the installation.
- (somehow wrong) build SDL as static obj and link it with the binary building a standalone executable

Good luck ;)